# redirect url Microsoft application

Tags: ajax, node.js, google-chrome-extension, oauth

Following the guide here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/howto/add-common-consent-manually#bk_RegisterServerApp

I have an API and I created chrome extension. The chrome extension on initialization, creates a popup which has the field name and email and on clicking "register". After that, I need to just want to authorize the user and get the microsoft id of the user so I can get other information like his/her calendar.

Question: What am I doing wrong and what is the redirect URL in this situation?

Example of the call in API

```
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: ' https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize',
   data: {response_type: 'code', client_id: config.clientId, resource:'https://outlook.office365.com/', state:generateUUID(), redirect_uri:'http://xxx'},
   success: function(result)
   {
     alert('woohoo')
   }
 });
```

Here is the article that told me to do the above: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2014/03/25/using-oauth2-to-access-calendar-contact-and-mail-api-in-exchange-online-in-office-365.aspx

Comment: So what error did you met?

Answer (score 0):

From the article you mention:

> redirect_uri [is the] URI in your app where users will be sent after
>   authorization. Must be registered in AAD.

This needs to be a valid URI that you have registered in the same place you got your client ID from.

Most OAuth2 systems are pretty good at telling you what you are doing wrong, so add an error handler to your AJAX call and inspect the response.

You also appear to be missing the "scope" parameter, which is required.

Reference:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code/